# Find before and after entry of record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table to find the given value before and after values.

For example want to show 1 value before and after of the given column `col2` value `125`.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE PreTest1
(
 col1 int,
 col2 int,
 col3 date,
 col4 time
);
```

Sample Data:

```
insert into PreTest1 values(111,124,'2018-01-01','00:10:11'),
                          (111,124,'2018-01-01','00:10:12'),
                          (111,122,'2018-01-01','00:10:17'),
                          (111,125,'2018-01-01','00:10:16'),
                          (111,125,'2018-01-01','00:10:13'),
                          (111,123,'2018-01-01','00:10:19'),
                          (111,130,'2018-01-01','00:10:18'),
                          (111,123,'2018-01-01','00:10:17'),
                          (111,121,'2018-01-01','00:09:11');
```

Query:

```
WITH C1 AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by col2,col3,col4) rn,*
    FROM PreTest1
)
SELECT * FROM 
(

    SELECT * FROM C1 WHERE rn IN (SELECT rn FROM C1 WHERE col2 = '125')
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM C1 WHERE rn IN ( SELECT rn - 1 FROM C1 WHERE col2 = '125') 
    UNION       
    SELECT * FROM C1 WHERE rn IN ( SELECT rn + 1 FROM C1 WHERE col2 = '125') 
) a
```

**Expected Output**:

```
col1        col2        col3       col4
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------------
111         124         2018-01-01 00:10:12.0000000
111         125         2018-01-01 00:10:16.0000000
111         123         2018-01-01 00:10:17.0000000
```

Comment: It's not really clear why these rows specifically. what are your `before` and `after` based on?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, The `before` and `after` is based on `date` + `time`.

Comment: SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,MAX(COL4)COL4 FROM #PreTest1
WHERE COL2 IN (122,125,130)
GROUP BY COL1,COL2,COL3

Comment: So from your sample data, the `col2` values should by `124`, `125` and `123`

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Yes! You're right.

Comment: Actually, `123` is interchangeable with `122` with this sample data, since they both have the exact same date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
WITH TMP1 AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by col1, col2 order by col3 desc, col4 desc) rang1, *
    FROM PreTest1
),
TMP2 as (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by col3 , col4, col2 desc) rang2, * 
from tmp1 where rang1=1
),
ValueRang as 
(
SELECT rang2 Position FROM TMP2 where col2=125
)
select * from tmp2
cross apply ValueRang
where tmp2.rang2 between Position-1 and Position + 1
```

Comment: My bad, I need `123` as after value in the result set. As shown in the expected result.

Comment: Are you sur you dont want 124, 125 and 122 ?